# What is this message icon in the lower right in Destiny 2?

Tags: pc, destiny-2

This icon has just been constantly flashing at me since I got to the Farm. I checked with the post bot, checked for friend invites or messages, Bnet message, nothing!

Any ideas?

[image: flashing message icon]

Comment: Consider deleting this, as you'll get your reputation back from the down votes and keep the Destiny 2 tag clean.

Comment: @TimmyJim Is this standard practice? Can you link a meta post which discusses this? I think the question is fine, having duplicates means there are more pages to land on from search results which increases the chances of stackexchange coming up on google. Being a duplicate is also not a reason to down vote.

Comment: @Annan at the time I posted my comment, this post had nothing but negative votes.  Now, it has a 3/-3 vote, which means the poster gained rep off this despite it being a duplicate.  It's not a standard I suppose, but it would have been beneficial for the OP to delete it (at the time).  It also keeps Arqade cleaner of duplicates.

Comment: @TimmyJim I had a quick look and found these guidelines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates) for not deleting "good duplicates". Specifically if the duplicate has significantly different phrasing or high view count. See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete).

Comment: @Annan maybe on other sites, but I can speak for Arqade, and I know that duplicates will certainly be received poorly most of the time here.  And the wording isn't really much different here compared to the duplicate.  The gist of both of them come down to "what is this icon in the bottom right of the screen"

Comment: @Annan thanks for the input, but when I googled for the words that popped into my head to describe the icon (specifically "message" which doesn't appear in the linked duplicate), I got no satisfactory results. "Message" is more specific than "box" anyway, so given that I don't care much about Arqade rep, I think I'll leave this up.

Answer (score 2):

It’s text chat. You can disable it in gameplay under settings